# InProc session state, web farm and unique and sticky SessionID?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, iis, session-cookies

I'd like to have InProc session state on servers in my webfarm and only share the unique SessionID (which I believe is transferred via browser cookie).

Is this possible?  We're planning to have custom object cache based on this SessionID that needs to be loaded only in certain scenarios.  If possible, I'd like to avoid creating custom session provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should avoid relying on internal details of ASP.NET (how it manages Session ID) - this behavior could change in the next .NET version or even before that if someone discovers a vulnerability in the current approach.

Instead create your own cookie - both reading and writing that cookie is a one-liner (`HttpResponse.SetCookie()` and `HttpRequest.Cookies[]`).